# JavaScript variable doesn't increment in function after getElementById of div

Tags: javascript, dom

I try to create a JavaScript function that will have one of the variables (var c) which will get the inner text of div tag (the text should be numbers, so somehow it should make variables of numbers) and increment by one when users click button.

**Problem**: The value of variable c is not incrementing. It increments once, but if user clicks again the button it still stays the same.

```
//variable $j is in for loop, and the size depends on the other part of the code.
<input type="button" value="Add more" onClick="addmore('.$j.');">
$kxx .= '<div id="K'.$j.'">'.$kx[$j].'</div>';
```

$kx is for example 1,4,5,2,33,33. And when the index is for example 1, instead of incrementing c (2,3,4,5...) if users click button twice, it gives them 2,2 - instead of 2,3.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addmore(index) {
    var c = document.getElementById("K"+index).innerHTML;
    c++;
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "odg" + index + c;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("inner"+index).appendChild(div);
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to treat c as an integer, convert it to one after getting it.

Comment: I put a number (integer) in variable c and it still can't increment.

Comment: Why would it increment? You do `c++`, but then you don't assign it back to where you got it. So your first line will always return the same number.

Comment: Yes I realize that now. Whenever users click the button, it will reset to the first line variable value and add 1 as it increments. So, how can I make it incremen, depending on how many times users click the button. I know I can make a var c outside of the function but I need it inside addmore();

Comment: Using c++ should increment the value of c, but my question is, what are you expecting to happen? All you're setting is the name property of your textarea with that incremented value, so how are you validating it isn't getting incremented?

Answer (score 0):

You're pulling that value out as a string.  JS doesn't know what to do with c++ because it sees it as string++.  Convert it to an int first with -

```
+c++
```

or

```
parseInt(c, 10)
```

updated to include parseInt() along with +c as suggested below.

Comment: It stil doesn't work. Even if I change var c = document.getElementById("K"+index).innerHTML; to var c = 11; It will no increment again. :(

Comment: I would suggest changing this into parseInt(c); the +c thing is rather ugly and makes the code unreadable

Comment: @weeknie: disagree in general regarding `+`, but in this one case, yeah. Also, should be `parseInt(c,10)`.